# Could I convert an android application to run under a java generic cellphone?

Tags: java, android, java-me

I have seen many questions about old java applications made for old cellphones trying to run under android cellphones.

Is it possible to run an android application (made 100% in java and android default libraries)  in an old java cellphone, converting somehow, the apk file into a jar file?

Imagine we using cool and useful android apps into those 3d gen cellphones...

---

I have discovered a project of a library that converts Android Activities and hardware interface to S60 5th edition phones.

Different from what many people think, this is widely important because these phones are cheaper and we can develop android applications (faster and more efficient) to them and use for personal and corporate purposes.

When we need to buy 30 of 50 phones, price is everything.

Comment: Generic old cellphones have screens that an Android phone would consider primitive.

Comment: Even if the language and bytecode is the same, the VM is not the same. All of the android classes would be out. Not to talk about the layouts in XML.

Comment: The question however could be asked like 'are there any tools that substitute android sdk to convert an android app to an application for old java phones?'  Sadly i can feel the answer will be no and even if yes, not having a lifecycle, such tools would not be what we want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a project to convert S60 phones to run android applications:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Porting_Android_(Java)_applications_to_Java_ME_on_S60_5th_Edition

Phones like nokia n95 and above are better suited with fast hardware and more memory than other java phones.

Comment: I did it. Tested an example of Android in a Nokia N8 and it worked, not very stable, but I will still be trying because there are still lot's of personal and corporate users and you can buy those at very small prices.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to run an android application (made 100% in java and android default libraries) in an old java cellphone, converting somehow, the apk file into a jar file?

In a word, no. There is little to no commonality between a JavaME device and an Android device in terms of application runtime environments.

You are welcome to attempt to port the Android OS to run on those devices, though they usually had far too little RAM for such a role.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible since the Android SDK relies on features that are supported by Android. Since you don't know if the Java based cellphone offers the same features I would say it's highly unlikely that it will ever run.